# Error en enum c# al colocar signo aritmetico

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy llenando un ComboBox a traves de un enum en MVC c#,en ese combo se llenan como options del combo operadores aritmeticos, pero solo requiero el simbolo(+,-,*,/), cuando coloco unicamente el signo me genera un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya le he colocado entre comillas dobles y simples pero me sigue marcando que se esperaba un identificador, hay tambien otra manera colocando el tag [Description(...)] pero no he podido bindear ese tag, la forma como bindeo el Combo es:

> ```
> @Html.DropDownList("DDLOperadores", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores)), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })
> ```

Comment: Hola, sabes que esos caracteres no son nombres validos?

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra tampoco son validos si los coloco entre comillas?

Comment: no. los nombres esos no son validos porque los nombres de la enumeracion no van entre comillas...

Comment: @gbianchi y si esos caracteres los coloco dentro de una etiqueta [Description] sabes como puedo bindearlos en un comboBox?

Comment: @Ivxn Mira la respuesta que te deje.

Comment: Aunque tambien es cierto que un tipo char puede ser definido como un entero. Puedes definir el enumerado con los valores enteros ASCII de cada carácter y luego aplicar (char)myIntCharValue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los `enum` no aceptan valores en comillas.

Para ello utiliza el decorador `[Description("...")]` para agregar un valor personalizado. Luego utiliza el siguiente metodo para poder leer el valor del decorador.

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: y si uso ese metodo que pones para obtener los Descriptions, como hago para bidearlos en mi @Html.DropDownList("DDLPais", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Paises.MuestraPais)), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })?

Comment: Utilizando tu mismo codigo de tu preguntas, quedaria algo asi. `@Html.DropDownList("DDLOperadores", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores.GetDescription())), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })`

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("DDLOperadores", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores.GetDescription())), "Selecciona el Tipo", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" }) - el nombre de tipop GetDescriptcion no existe en el tipo EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores

Comment: ¿Copiaste el método tal cual lo coloque? debes colocar el código en un archivo de clase y cada vez que llames a un `enum` te debería servir el GetDescription. A mi me funciona.

Comment: Coloque el metodo en la misma clase donde tengo la enumeracion es asi como debe estar?

Comment: Ok ya lo tengo, ahora, se puede obtener el indice que le ponemos al valor de la opcion en la enumeracion (Multiplicacion=1,Suma=2,Resta=3), como lo obtendria?

Comment: Si necesitas sacar el 1,2,3... debes hacer esto `(int)EnumOperadores.MuestraOperadores.Multiplicacion`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola básicamente un enumerado es una convención de nombres para tipos enteros. No se pueden asignar valores de tipo cadena en ellos.
Si quieres usar algo parecido a un enumerado que devuelva cadenas deberías hacer algo asi

```
public static class MyOperators
{
    public const string Less = "<"; 
    public const string LessOrEqual = "<=";
    public const string Greater = ">";
    public const string GreaterOrEqual = ">=";
    public const string Add = "+";
    public const string Minus = "-";
}
```